# Cookie is not send with request to another sub-domain

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

Current set up:

```
https://abc.domain.com
https://api.domain.com
```

**Backend**

`https://abc.domain.com` exposes cookie like:

```
var responseCookie = ResponseCookie.from("xyzname", "xyzvalue")
                    .domain(".domain.com").path("/")
                    .secure(true).sameSite("Strict").httpOnly(true)
                    .build();

response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, responseCookie.toString())
```

**Frontend**

`https://abc.domain.com` frontend (stencil.js web component) API fetching config:

```
return fetch("https://api.domain.com/something", {
    credentials: "same-origin",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Accept-language': currentLanguage
    }
```

**API Gateway**

`https://api.domain.com` (jhipster based application) configuration:

```
jhipster:
  cors:
    allowed-origins: 'http://abc.domain.com,https://abc.domain.com'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-alert,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-error,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-params'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

So, generally, page `https://abc.domain.com` exposes secured, strict http only cookie with domain `.domain.com`.
Frontend is trying to make call to `https://api.domain.com`. I would expect to see that cookie included in request, but it is not available there.
Any tips?